# Facebook SDK for Android 3.0: UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, facebook

```
 01-29 21:06:00.601: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
     ... 11 more
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that is not currently open.
     at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:977)
     at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:501)
     at ***.MainActivity.postToFacebook(MainActivity.java:105)
     ... 14 more
```

The exception is thrown in line

```
 session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
 // Check for publish permissions
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);


                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);


                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Not enough permissions",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

What does this exception mean and how to fix it?

Comment: @DmitroTitov I've put together a couple of articles which fully explain opening a Facebook session and requesting additional permissions: [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html) and [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-requesting.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dmytro, as per my comment, I've put together a couple of articles which fully explain opening a Facebook session and requesting additional permissions: [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html) and [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-requesting.html). Hope you and others find it beneficial and save time getting started with the SDK! :)

> **Edit:** The reason you are getting this exception is because you can't
>   request new permissions on a non-open session. You need to open your
>   session before requesting new permissions or making other Facebook API
>   requests. I've put together a guide in the articles linked to above
>   which ensure a Facebook API request (such as posting to a user's feed
>   and so forth) is not made until the the user's session is open and the
>   user has the required permissions.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @bluefeet, noted. Thanks. And my answer above edited to answer Dmytro's question better. (Forgive me all - and I normally do - but posting code here would have amounted a very very long answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It means that the session you are requesting permissions for is inactive/expired. You need to re-establish the session before you can request permissions.

Comment: @DmytroTitov I've put together a couple of articles which fully explain opening a Facebook session and requesting additional permissions: [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html) and [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-requesting.html).

Comment: @AdilHussain
Thank you. You can write an answer and I'll mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call session.openForPublish(Session.OpenRequest openRequest) before calling requestNewPublishPermissions?

Comment: No, I didn't. I follow the instruction in this article: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/ There's no any mention of "openForPublish()" in it... So, should I?

Comment: Yes,you must open the session somewhere.

Comment: @DmytroTitov I've put together a couple of articles which fully explain opening a Facebook session and requesting additional permissions: [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-opening-session.html) and [here](http://adilatwork.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/facebook-android-sdk-30-requesting.html).